# How to handle device change in Flutter app using encrypted hive boxes?

Tags: flutter, encryption, flutter-hive

I am looking at a secure way to store user data in a Flutter app - both offline on the device and as a backup in the cloud. One possible way would be to use encrypted boxes in hive in combination with flutter_secure_storage. Like so:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  const secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  // if key not exists return null
  final encryptionKeyString = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  if (encryptionKeyString == null) {
    final key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    await secureStorage.write(
      key: 'key',
      value: base64UrlEncode(key),
    );
  }
  final key = await secureStorage.read(key: 'key');
  final encryptionKeyUint8List = base64Url.decode(key!);
  print('Encryption key Uint8List: $encryptionKeyUint8List');
  final encryptedBox = await Hive.openBox('vaultBox', encryptionCipher: HiveAesCipher(encryptionKeyUint8List));
  encryptedBox.put('secret', 'Hive is cool');
  print(encryptedBox.get('secret'));
}
```

I could now also store the encrypted boxes in a cloud storage solution like S3. One of the goals is that also developers and admins are not able to read the data.

What is unclear to me is how I would handle a device switch. Two possible scenarios come to mind:

1. A user loses their device, buys a new one and restores it from an iCloud backup
2. A user buys a second device

For the sake of simplicity, let's only look at iOS. Is the encryption key available on the two devices from Keystore? So could I theoretically identify the user (maybe also by a user id stored in Keystore), download the encrypted Hive Boxes to the device and decrypt them using the encryption key from iOS Keystore? In case (1) the data is probably even restored from the backup.

It also looks like this is even more difficult on Android since the encryption keys from the Android Keystore are not available after restoration (as far as I understand).

So maybe the best approach is use either

1. User input (like a hashed password)
2. An exportable token (like a easy to remember, auto-generated password, maybe stored in a printable QR code)

In these cases the data is lost when the key is lost. But they seem like the safest option to me.

Am I missing something? Is there a better or standard way to handle this problem?